# Implement Cascading drop down lists within ASP.NET Gridview control

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I'm using SQLDataSource for my ASP.NET Gridview control. The user needs to be able to edit a row but two fields will have drop down lists. The information within one drop down lists depends on what is chosen within the first drop down list. How can this be achieved by using SQLDataSource only? If not, is there a good resource for doing it without SQLDataSource? This is [one resource I found](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=221) and tried to use but it only works when it is in ItemTemplateField.
Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" Width="1100px" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="CustomerID,StateID" DataSourceID="SqlDSCustomers" GridLines="Vertical">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" Visible="false" HeaderText="CustomerID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="Customer" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryEdit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDSCountries" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Country_ID") %>' DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="Country_ID"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSCountries" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnnMain %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Country_ID], [Country] FROM [Countries]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDSStates" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StateID") %>' DataTextField="State" DataValueField="StateID"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSStates" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnnMain %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [StateID], [State] FROM [States] WHERE ([Country_ID] = @Country_ID)">
          <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCountryEdit" Name="Country_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
    </asp:CommandField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" ForeColor="Black" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
</asp:GridView>
```

This current code works until I change the country. So, all the fields show the correct information and the country drop down list shows all the countries we use. The state drop down list shows the correct states for the country preselected but, once I change the country, I get this error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

This is the Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(),
>   XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound
>   control.]    System.Web.UI.Page.GetDataItem() +3210970
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(String expression) +34
>   ASP.editcorporate_aspx.__DataBinding__control106(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\WebSites\MyWebApp\EditCustomer.aspx:357
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +92
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +23
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974

If there is anymore information needed, please let me know. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In this situation I'd suggest refreshing ddlStateEdit from a JSON data source using jquery.ajax.  You can find many tutorials for doing this type of thing.  Here's one that looks pretty good: [link](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/)

Comment: How do I retrieve the information from SQL using that approach?

Comment: You could create a page or service (.aspx is fine) that runs your SQL command and returns the data table as JSON (you'll want to add the NewtonSoftJson Nuget package to your project) using a serialization function like the example here:

[link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: Your jQuery would then just access that page and parse the results as JSON.  You can pass in the country parameter as a querystring.  Something like the following...

Comment: `var country = $('#ddlCountryEdit').val();
var states = '';  
$.get("getStates.aspx?country=" + country, function (data) {  
    states = $.parseJSON(data);  
}).done(function () { populateStates() });  
  
function populateStates() {  
    var options = '';  
    $.each(states, function () {  
        options += '<option value="' + this.Country_ID + '">' + this.Country_Name + '</option>';  
    });  
    $('#ddlStateEdit').append(options);  
};`